# Difference between Objects (javascript and jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

This may be a strange question. I'm trying to fuse two arrays together, but the read out is showing them as separate types of objects. The first type, gathered by the .serializeArray() jquery function is showing as this when I alert them:

```
[object Object]
```

The second, which I am getting from pushing each option in using a more JS way, shows as this:

```
[object HTMLOptionElement]
```

Here's my code below:

```
   incrCopy();
   enableSubmit();
   disableReset();

   var linkedInArray = [];
   $('form select option.linked-in').each( function() {
   linkedInArray.push(this);
   })
   //These alert the second way

   prevVals = $("form").serializeArray();
   //They alert the first way
   prevVals.push(linkedInArray);
   alert(prevVals);
```

Anyone have an idea on what I'm missing here?

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure of the difference academically, but I realized when I called $(this) instead of 'this' in the each loop, the objects looked the same.

Comment: I was just about to put that in as an answer.  The HTML element doesn't become a jQuery object until wrapped in `$()`

Comment: Well, `serializeArray` collects the values from the form fields and creates an array of objects (http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/). `linkedInArray.push(this);` directly adds the DOM element to the array. You are just doing two different things.

Comment: You'll get better information if you use `console.log`, and `console.dir` via the developer console than you ever will via `alert`.

Comment: Array does not equal list in js. They are completely different structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a difference between jQuery  and JavaScript. That is how [`serializeArray`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) works. It doesn't return a list of HTML elements, it returns a list of plain-old-objects with name/value properties.

For example, were it to find something like this:

```
<input name="user[eye_color]" value="brown" />
<input name="user[age]" value="47" />
```

it would return an array of plain-old-objects, looking something like this:

```
[
  {
    name: "user[eye_color]",
    value: "brown"
  },
  {
    name: "user[age]",
    value: 47
  }
]
```

Conversly, your first loop iterates over a jQuery selector, where each element is a [native `HTMLElement`](http://krook.org/jsdom/HTMLElement.html) of some kind (`HTMLDivElement`, `HTMLInputElement`, `HTMLTableElement`, etc).